# Why am I not able to insert a value to a StringBuilder inside a LINQ Select() query

Tags: c#, linq, stringbuilder

Why am I not able to Insert string values from a List into a StringBuilder through the LINQ `Select()` query?

Given the code below I would expect my built string at the end to be `{CBA}` but instead it is `{}`.

What am I missing?

```
var testList = new List<string>
{
   "A",
   "B",
   "C"
};

var testStringBuilder = new StringBuilder("{}");
testList.Select(y => testStringBuilder.Insert(1,y));
```

Comment: Linq is lazy. You're not iterating over your query, and therefore the delegate passed to `Select` is not being executed. What you want is a `foreach` loop, not linq.

Comment: If you put that as an answer I can accept it

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be using `Select` like this, that method is meant to be used to project items into a new structure, not for looping over things. Linq here is meaningless and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Use LINQ for querying data sources and use `for` or `foreach` loops for working with data or modifying it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Linq is lazy - most linq methods aren't executed until you actually iterate over your query.

`Select` isn't the right thing to be using, anyway. It's a mapping function - for each element in the collection, it transforms it in some way, and returns the transformed element. It's normally a very bad idea to write a `Select` (or any linq method) which has side-effects.

What you're doing is taking each element and doing something with it - that's the use-case for a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var element in testList)
{
    testStringBuilder.Insert(1, element);
}
```

---

Don't be tempted to use `List<T>.ForEach` for this. It's only available on `List<T>`, and not on any of the other collections: it was deliberately left out of Linq, as its existence was regarded as a mistake. See [Eric Lippert's reasoning](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/).

Answer (score 0):

`Select` returns a list of `StringBuilder`

You must make a loop to do that. Using `for` loop

```
foreach(var y in testList)
{
    testStringBuilder.Insert(1,y);
}
```

or `ForEach` of linq.

```
testList.ForEach(y => testStringBuilder.Insert(1,y));
```

Comment: OK thanks for adding the explanation, but it doesn't really make any sense. `Select` is using a loop in the same way `ForEach` is. We should be advocating doing a plain `for` or `foreach` loop.

Comment: "*or ForEach of linq.*" -- `ForEach` isn't part of linq. It was deliberately left out of linq.

Answer (score -1):

As @canton7 said, Linq is lazy.

You can force to execute the select query you created using the `ToList()` method

```
testList.Select(y => testStringBuilder.Insert(1, y)).ToList()
```

However, in order to imporve effiecency, the `foreach` loop is highly recomended

**Edit**

Can somebody explain me why i got -1?
This method works, I never said that's the best, but I think that it helps to better understanding how linq works